# Looping through all files in directory VBA

Tags: vba, loops, directory

I'm trying to loop through all files in a given directory using VBA and replace a few words in each file before saving it in another directory. The method I'm using is:

```
With Application
        Do While Len(fileName) > 0
```

Where fileName is:

```
fileName = Dir$("C:\FOLDER\" & "*")
```

After I run the code I have:

```
fileName = Dir
        Loop
```

However, after it goes back to the top of the loop, it does not pick up any more files. I am sure there are multiple files in the given directory.. Any ideas?

Comment: Works for me. Can you show the complete code (only the relevant, not the one where you do your file modification)

Answer (score 1):

Test it in separate Subs, this two codes works.

```
 Sub LoopAllFiles()
        Dim StrFile As String
         StrFile = Dir$("C:\FOLDER\" & "*")

        Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
            StrFile = Dir
        Loop

End Sub



Sub LoopAllFiles()
    Dim StrFile As String
    StrFile = Dir("C:\FOLDER\" & "*")
    Do While StrFile <> ""
         StrFile = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks all. I got it working - I think it didn't like my variable declaration